# Pygame audio code not working

Tags: python, audio, numpy, pygame, trigonometry

This code seems to run ok, but doesn't actually *do* anything it should, other than opening the pygame window. I am looking for a sound to be played when the 'z' key is pressed.

Can anyone see a problem with this code?

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math
import numpy

size = (1200, 720)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
pygame.display.set_caption('Nibbles!')

SAMPLE_RATE = 22050 ## This many array entries == 1 second of sound.

def SineWave(freq=1000,volume=16000,length=1):
    num_steps = length*SAMPLE_RATE
    s = []
    for n in range(num_steps):
        value = int(math.sin(n * freq * (6.28318/SAMPLE_RATE) * length)*volume)
        s.append( [value,value] )
    x_arr = array(s)
    return x_arr

def SquareWave(freq=1000,volume=100000,length=1):
    length_of_plateau = SAMPLE_RATE / (2*freq)
    s = []
    counter = 0
    state = 1
    for n in range(length*SAMPLE_RATE):
        if state == 1:
            value = volume
        else:
            value = -volume
        s.append( [value,value] )

        counter += 1
        if counter == length_of_plateau:
            counter = 0
            if state == 1:
                state = -1
            else:
                state = 1

    x_arr = array(s)
    return x_arr

def MakeSound(arr):
    return pygame.sndarray.make_sound(arr)

def PlaySquareWave(freq=1000):
    MakeSound(SquareWave(freq)).play()

def PlaySineWave(freq=1000):
    MakeSound(SineWave(freq)).play()

def StopSineWave(freq=1000):
    MakeSound(SineWave(freq)).fadeout(350)

def StopSquareWave(freq=1000):
    MakeSound(SquareWave(freq)).fadeout(350)

_running = True
while _running:

    SineWaveType = 'Sine'
    SquareWaveType = 'Square'
    d = {SineWaveType:SquareWaveType, SquareWaveType:SineWaveType}
    Type = SineWaveType

    for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                _running = False

            if Type == 'Sine':

                if event.type == KEYDOWN:

                    #lower notes DOWN
                    if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                        _running = False

                    if event.key == K_ENTER:
                        Type = d[Type]  #Toggle

                    elif event.key == K_z:
                        PlaySineWave(130.81)

                if event.type == KEYUP:

                    #lower notes UP

                    if event.key == K_z:
                        StopSineWave(130.81).fadeout(350)       #fade sound by .35 seconds

            elif Type == 'Square':

                if event.type == KEYDOWN:

                    #lower notes DOWN
                    if event.key == K_z:
                        PlaySquareWave(130.81)

                if event.type == KEYUP:

                    #lower notes UP

                    if event.key == K_z:
                        StopSquareWave(130.81).fadeout(350)     #fade sound by .35 seconds

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: You realise that your `_running` loop does absolutely nothing but wait for `QUIT`, right? At what point are you expecting this code to actually *do* anything?

Comment: I feel stupid now, didn't notice this at all. I have edited the original post, now it won't even open the pygame window, am I still missing something here?

Comment: You really need to get to grips with Python's indentation-based scoping - everything from `if Type == 'Sine':` on down is **outside** the `while` loop.

Comment: This is not the case with my actual code, that is how it pasted here, it is all indented correctly as far as I can see, original post has been edited again to show this.

Comment: You should only go through `event in pygame.event.get()` once per loop, otherwise you could discard one event while looking for another.

Comment: There is still no window being opened, it seems to open very briefly, but quit almost immediately again...

Comment: Run this code in console/terminal/cmd.exe to see error message.

Comment: There is undefined function `array()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT (2019.03.06):** now code works with Python 3 - thanks to [Tomasz Gandor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338797/tomasz-gandor) suggestions in the commentary.

---

Some modifications:

- you have to fadeout existing sound not create new one to fadeout (because pygame will play both at the same time) - I use `curren_played` to keep existing sound.
- keys `ESCAPE` and `ENTER` don't have to check sound type.
- you forgot `pygame.init()` which initialize screen, mixer and other things.
- because i had problem with square wave so I use sine wave in example.
- I add sonund to `c` key - so you can play two sounds at the same time
- I use uppercase names for constant values like `SINE_WAVE_TYPE`.

You could create waves before `mainloop` and keep it in `current_played` and generated new waves in `current_played` when you press `RETURN` 
.

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
import math
import numpy

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# functions
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

def SineWave(freq=1000, volume=16000, length=1):

    num_steps = length * SAMPLE_RATE
    s = []

    for n in range(num_steps):
        value = int(math.sin(n * freq * (6.28318/SAMPLE_RATE) * length) * volume)
        s.append( [value, value] )

    return numpy.array(s, dtype=numpy.int32) # added dtype=numpy.int32 for Python3

def SquareWave(freq=1000, volume=100000, length=1):

    num_steps = length * SAMPLE_RATE
    s = []

    length_of_plateau = SAMPLE_RATE / (2*freq)

    counter = 0
    state = 1

    for n in range(num_steps):

        value = state * volume
        s.append( [value, value] )

        counter += 1

        if counter == length_of_plateau:
            counter = 0
            state *= -1

    return numpy.array(s, dtype=numpy.int32) # added dtype=numpy.int32 for Python3

def MakeSound(arr):
    return pygame.sndarray.make_sound(arr)

def MakeSquareWave(freq=1000):
    return MakeSound(SquareWave(freq))

def MakeSineWave(freq=1000):
    return MakeSound(SineWave(freq))

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
# main program
#----------------------------------------------------------------------

pygame.init()

size = (1200, 720)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.HWSURFACE | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
pygame.display.set_caption('Nibbles!')

SAMPLE_RATE = 22050 ## This many array entries == 1 second of sound.

SINE_WAVE_TYPE = 'Sine'
SQUARE_WAVE_TYPE = 'Square'

sound_types = {SINE_WAVE_TYPE:SQUARE_WAVE_TYPE, SQUARE_WAVE_TYPE:SINE_WAVE_TYPE}

current_type = SINE_WAVE_TYPE

current_played = { 'z': None, 'c': None }

_running = True
while _running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            _running = False

        # some keys don't depend on `current_type`

        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                _running = False

            if event.key == K_RETURN:
                current_type = sound_types[current_type]  #Toggle
                print('new type:', current_type) # added () for Python3

        # some keys depend on `current_type`

        if current_type == SINE_WAVE_TYPE:

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:

                #lower notes DOWN

                if event.key == K_z:
                    print(current_type, 130.81) # added () for Python3
                    current_played['z'] = MakeSineWave(130.81)
                    current_played['z'].play()

                elif event.key == K_c:
                    print(current_type, 180.81) # added () for Python3
                    current_played['c'] = MakeSineWave(180.81)
                    current_played['c'].play()

            elif event.type == KEYUP:

                #lower notes UP

                if event.key == K_z:
                    current_played['z'].fadeout(350)
                elif event.key == K_c:
                    current_played['c'].fadeout(350)

        elif current_type == SQUARE_WAVE_TYPE:

            if event.type == KEYDOWN:

                #lower notes DOWN

                if event.key == K_z:
                    print(current_type, 80.81) # added () for Python3
                    current_played['z'] = MakeSineWave(80.81)
                    #current_played['z'] = MakeSquareWave(130.81)
                    current_played['z'].play()

                elif event.key == K_c:
                    print(current_type, 180.81) # added () for Python3
                    current_played['c'] = MakeSineWave(180.81)
                    #current_played['c'] = MakeSquareWave(130.81)
                    current_played['c'].play()

            elif event.type == KEYUP:

                #lower notes UP

                if event.key == K_z:
                    current_played['z'].fadeout(350)
                elif event.key == K_c:
                    current_played['c'].fadeout(350)

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: It works! For Python 3 run `2to3` (just `print` statements), and also specify `dtype=np.int32` (`import numpy as np`) for numpy arrays.

Comment: @TomaszGandor - thanks. This code is almost 5 years old but with your suggestions it can still be useful. (PL: Dzięki. Ten kod ma prawie 5 lat ale z Twoim sugestiami wciąż może być przydatny)